# How does "comme de bien entendu" compare to "bien entendu"?

Tags: expressions

> **Comme de bien entendu**, une fois le paquet ouvert à mon domicile, j'ai constaté que le produit était incomplet.

I have always wondered:

1) How does this expression compare to saying "bien entendu"? Perhaps, more emphatic?

2) What is the function of "de" here? Because I have also heard "comme bien entendu" and "tout comme bien entendu".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Comme de bien entendu*** is a set expression built a similar way than these other idiomatic ones:

- *comme **de** coutume*
- *comme **de** juste*
- *comme si **de** rien n'était*
- *plus que **de** raison*.

It is indeed used to emphasize *bien entendu*.

*De* role is, [according to the TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de),

> II.− *De* marque une relation syntaxique; il est introducteur de subst., de pron. ou d'inf. en fonction de compl., de suj., d'attribut, d'appos., ou en fonction expressive.
> …
> B.− [*De* introducteur de suj., d'attributs, d'appos.; de signifie « le fait de », en parlant d'un fait particulier.]
> 2. **De** + attribut
> a) **De** + attribut du suj.
> …
> − Dans des gallicismes
> ε) *Comme de juste, comme de raison, comme de vrai,* (fam.); *comme de bien entendu, comme de sûr* (pop.). Comme cela est juste, de raison, vrai, bien entendu, sûr. *Je lui payerai sa peine, comme **de** raison* (Staël, Lettres div.,1793, p. 475). *Pour lui, « le général », c'est l'général Anselme!... Pas, Chalumeau? − Comme **de** sûr ! répondit le planton* (Gyp, Souv. pte fille,1927, p. 141).

It can hardly be replaced by *comme bien entendu*. The latter cannot end a sentence and otherwise, *comme* is used to start a subordinate clause while *comme de bien entendu* is itself a full subordinate clause.

> *Comme, bien entendu, ce n'est pas de votre faute, nous prendrons la réparation sous garantie.*

As of course it's not your fault, we take the repair under warranty.

> *Comme de bien entendu, le parking est payant alors je suis venu en bus.*

Needless to say, the car park is not free so I came by bus.

I never heard *tout comme bien entendu* without commas. Otherwise its usage is slightly different, e.g.:

> *Tout comme, bien entendu, les pneus avant, il a aussi fallu changer les pneus arrière.*
>
> Just like, obviously, the front tires, the rear ones also had to be replaced.